# Bad JSONArray parsing on client-side while putting data into Datatable

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, datatable, arrays

I have this code on the server-side:

```
@RequestMapping(value="friendFamily/getFriendsByUserId", method=RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = "application/json")
public String getFriendsByUserId(@RequestParam("userId") Long userId){
//....
List<User> friendsList = (((ArrayList<Friends>)session.createCriteria(Friends.class).
                add(Restrictions.eq("person", user)).list()).get(0)).getFriends();
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
for (User tempUser: friendsList){
    array.put(new JSONObject(tempUser));
}
return array.toString();
```

And in the client-side I want to put this data into datatable:

```
$("#browseFriendsAndFamily").click(function(){
          var contPath='<%=request.getContextPath()%>';
          $.get(contPath + "/friendFamily/getFriendsByUserId",
              "userId="+loggedUser.id, function(friendsList){
                  $("#friendFamilyDialog").dialog("open");
                  friendsTable = $("#friendsTable").dataTable({
                      "bJQueryUI": true,
                       "aoColumnDefs": [ {"bVisible": false, "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [3]}],
                       "bSortClasses": false
                  });
                  familyTable = $("#familyTable").dataTable({
                      "bJQueryUI": true,
                      "aoColumnDefs": [ {"bVisible": false, "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [3]}],
                      "bSortClasses": false
                  });
                  for(var i=0, length=friendsList.length; i<length; i++){
                      friendsTable.fnAddData(friendsList[i].name, friendsList[i].surname,
                      friendsList[i].login, friendsList[i].id);
                      console.log(friendsList[i].login);
                  }     
               });                 
            });
```

But in datatables, if I got for example person with name="Paul" surname="Smith" login="Paul123" id="38" it behave like it doesn't understand it like an array of JSONs but like an array of Strings and it puts in name column "P", in surname column "a", in login column "u", in one word - it treats it "doesn't understand" that is JSON, which is a little bit strange for me. What am I doing wrong? If I write:

```
console.log(friendsList[i].login)
```

I see correct values, for example "Paul123". I would be very happy if anybody helps me - thank you in advance.

**@Update**: i see now a little bit strange behavior - even if I do this:

```
for(var i=0, length=friendsList.length; i<length; i++){
   var name = friendsList[i].name;
   var surname = friendsList[i].surname;
   var login = friendsList[i].login;
   var id = friendsList[i].id;
    friendsTable.fnAddData(name, surname,
         login, id);
   console.log(friendsList[i].surname);
}
```

It **still** behave in the same way... I see in browser that variable values are correct but in datatables it works in the same way as before, it puts in table's columns further 'char' values from variable name (it treats it like a 'C-string')...

Answer (score 0):

**@Answered**. Here is solution from Datatables forum -> [Datatables treats String variable like a C-string(char[])? (click)](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/20435/datatables-treats-string-variable-like-a-c-stringchar#Item_3)